# Como entrar com novos dados para predição (texto)?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Sou novo em Python e novo em Machine Learning. Construí um algoritmo para que ele seja treinado para classificar textos. Para que possa predizer em qual categoria se encaixa determinado texto.

O treino e o score, estão funcionando. Agora, minha dúvida é com relação a novos dados. Como entro com estes dados para que seja predito em qual categoria se encaixa?

Tentei, como no código a seguir, mas não consegui, não entendi ainda como pode ser feito. Segue o código e agradeço a ajuda.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
import re
import string
import sklearn
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="10.1....", port="5432", database="aplicationNames", user="aplicationNames", password="aplicationNames")

# dataframe com o texto dos sintomas e a categoria do cat
df = pd.read_sql(
    "SELECT dsobservacaoclinica1, cdcatcategoria AS cat FROM iaconsultas limit 500",
    conn)
# criação das colunas do dataframe
df.columns = ['texto', 'cat']
# print(df) #imprimindo o dataframe
# Pegando os textos puros da coluna texto, para normalização.
# textos puros terão de ter um índice
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('-', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('/', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('+', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('ões', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace(';', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('#', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('~', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace(':', '')
df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.lower().str.split()
stop = stopwords.words("portuguese")
textosPuros = df['texto'].apply(lambda x: [w for w in x if not w in stop])


# textosPuros = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('\n', '')

# print(textosPuros)

def remove(string):
    novo = []
    for x in string:
        item = x
        for y in ['\n', '\t', '/', '.', '-', '(', ')']:
            item = item.replace(y, "")
        novo.append(item)
    return novo


# print(textosPuros)

textoMinusculo = textosPuros

# print(textoMinusculo)

textoLimpo = textoMinusculo  # [item for item in textoMinusculo if item not in ['\n', '\t']]

# textoLimpo = re.sub()
dicionario = set()
for lista in textoLimpo:
    dicionario.update(lista)
# imprime dicionario
print("Dicioonario")
# dicionario = {y.strip('\t\n.,/\1234567890();:-_') for y in dicionario}
print(dicionario)
# imprime as palavras limpas
print(textoLimpo)

# Atribui cada palavra a uma posicao no dicionario
totalDePalavras = len(dicionario)
tuplas = zip(dicionario, np.arange(totalDePalavras))
tradutor = {palavra: indice for palavra, indice in tuplas}

# Mostra a quantidade total de palavras
print("Total de palavras: ")
print(totalDePalavras)


def vetorizar_texto(texto, tradutor):
    vetor = [0] * len(tradutor)

    for palavra in texto:
        if palavra in tradutor:
            posicao = tradutor[palavra]
            vetor[posicao] += 1

    return vetor


# Vincula os textos quebrados a posicao no vetor
vetoresDeTexto = [vetorizar_texto(texto, tradutor) for texto in textoLimpo]
marcas = df['cat']
# Define o conjunto de dados X
X = np.array(vetoresDeTexto)
# Define o conjunto de dados Y (labels)
Y = np.array(marcas.tolist())

# Define porcentagem do treino
porcentagem_de_treino = 0.8

# Separa o tamanho do treino a partir da porcentagem
tamanho_do_treino = int(porcentagem_de_treino * len(Y))
# O restante fica para a validacao
tamanho_de_validacao = (len(Y) - tamanho_do_treino)

print("Frases disponiveis: ")
# print(len(Y))
print("Frases para treino: ")
# print(tamanho_do_treino)
print("Frase para validacao: ")
# print(tamanho_de_validacao)

# Separa os dados de treino
treino_dados = X[0:tamanho_do_treino]
# Separa as marcacoes de treino
treino_marcacoes = Y[0:tamanho_do_treino]
# Separa os dados de validacao
validacao_dados = X[tamanho_do_treino:]
# Separa as marcacoes de validacao
validacao_marcacoes = Y[tamanho_do_treino:]

print("Textos usados na validacao: ")
# print(textoLimpo[tamanho_do_treino:])
print("Validacao Marcacoes: ")
print(validacao_marcacoes)

clf = LogisticRegression()  # MultinomialNB() obtive 62% de acerto#GaussianNB()
clf.fit(treino_dados, treino_marcacoes)
# resp = clf.predict(validacao_dados)

accuracy = clf.score(validacao_dados, validacao_marcacoes)

print("Indice de acerto do algoritmo: ")
print("%.2f " % round(accuracy * 100) + "%\n")
# salvando  treino com pickle
file_name = 'treino.sav'
pickle._dump(clf, open(file_name, 'wb'))
# salvando treino com joblib
file_name_joblib = 'treino_joblib.sav'
joblib.dump(clf, file_name_joblib)
'''for cat in resp:
    print("cat {:16s}".format(cat))
'''
```

Este acima, é o código para treinamento. Abaixo, o código que seria para predição, com uma entrada de dados, "minha"

```
def predict():
    pr = pd.read_csv('csv_to_predict.csv', sep=';', header=0, usecols=[0])
    pred_cols = list(pr.columns.values)[0]
    test = ['buscar resultado']
    tvect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=1)
    X_test = test #vetoresDeTexto(test, tradutor)  # tvect.transform(test)
    # carregar modelo salvo para predição com pickle
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))
    # carregando modelo salvo para predição com joblib
    loaded_model_joblib = joblib.load(file_name_joblib)
    result = loaded_model_joblib.predict(X_test)
    print(result)


predict()
```

Erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/categoriesTest/DataBases.py", line 167, in <module>
    predict()
  File "C:/Python/categoriesTest/DataBases.py", line 163, in predict
    result = loaded_model_joblib.predict(X_test)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 324, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 300, in decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 441, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['buscar resultado'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Eu já tive esse problema, mas não com predição relacionado à texto. Se você colocar colchetes deve funcionar: `result = loaded_model_joblib.predict([X_test])`

Comment: @LorranSutter opa! acabo tendo mesmo erro. Acredito estar fazendo algo errado relacionado a predição mesmo.

Comment: A respeito da predição não posso mesmo afirmar se está incorreto, mas o erro certamente não é relacionado à ela. Sua entrada contém só um elemento (array unidimensional) e o `predict` pede um array bidimensional (uma matriz ou dataframe). Tente seguir a recomendação  que o próprio erro te dá: usar um `X_test.reshape(-1,1)` ou `X_test.reshape(1,-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre na seguinte parte do código:

```
 result = loaded_model_joblib.predict(X_test)
```

basta modificar para:

result = loaded_model_joblib.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))

ou caso o erro continue:

```
 result = loaded_model_joblib.predict(X_test.reshape(1,-1))
```

não irei entrar em detalhes do porque o erro ocorre. basta começar a olhar os shape de suas arrays. e quando for fazer predição em apenas um instancia basta lembrar que o algoritmo espera uma array de 3 dimensões não duas.

por exemplo 1 linha do data frame:
[1,2,3,4,5,6]

mas o algoritmo espera:
[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

isso é um erro muito comum logo você não terá mais problemas.

Comment: Obrigado. Mesmo eu entrando com um texto, devo colocar este reshape? Digo, manualmente.

Comment: Esse reshape é somente para quando você utilizar os métodos .predict, .fit ou .fit_transform do scikit-learn. de uma olhada no ipython como fica a array depois desses reshapes que você irá entender melhor o porque deles.